# Getting component using PF('WidgetVar').show() is not working with IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, primefaces

I have a `p:dialog` with a widget var, and a button that opens that dialog simply by saying `PF(widgetvarval).show()` works like a charm on Firefox and chrome but not on IE. it gives error that `show()` is undefined ..

dialog:

```
<p:dialog modal="true" responsive="true"
    onHide=" window.close();" widgetVar="edit#{student.id}"
                                    resizable="false"
                                    onShow=" setTimeout(() => {
                this.showDialog = true;
            }, 0);">
</p:dialog>
```

and the button:

```
<p:commandButton update="@form" process="@this"
oncomplete="PF('edit#{student.id}').show();" event="onclick"

                                </p:commandButton>
```

ERROR I get in IE:

> Error: Unable to get property 'show' of undefined or null reference

is there anyway I can make it work on IE?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Which IE version are you dealing with? It is important for your questions to state the version of the software being involved. IE, JSF, Primefaces.. That way the people helping can replicate your issue. Also, why do you assign a dynamic `widgetVar` attribute? If you want dynamic content I encourage you to have a single `p:dialog` and update its content dynamically. You'll have better performance too.

Comment: version 11. but I'm not sure what version is the user going to be using

Comment: As I said, you'd better have an static `widgetVar` value. For example `widgetVar="infoDialog"`

Comment: @XtremeBiker but I have a list of items, each has its own dialog

Comment: @XtremeBiker it seems that IE doesn't recognise PF(), but i am not sure what alternative I can use instead

Comment: I could guess something like this in your case. Better have a single dialog, out from the list. When you select an item, set the selected item in the managed bean, then display the dialog with the info of the selected item. Having each list item rendering a dialog in HTML is a performance leak.

Comment: `PF` is recognized in IE. You can check it in the showcase: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/dialog/basic.xhtml

Comment: @XtremeBiker I will improve it in the future but right now i just need this to work with the smallest change possible because I need to go live today, so if there coud be any way that makes IE see the primefaces component ??

Comment: Check the id the dialog components have at client side in IE (with the inspector, F12). It should exactly the `widgetVar` value being referenced.

Comment: OH, then why it doesn't work on IE when i used it on my app :(( @XtremeBiker

Answer (score 0):

I am using like this, its works .

```
<p:commandButton value="Hi !" onclick="PF('dlg').show();"></p:commandButton>

<p:dialog widgetVar="dlg" modal="true" >
      <h:outputLabel value="Hello" />                   
</p:dialog>
```